# jQuery open submenu on first click, go to url on second if there is href attribut

Tags: jquery, menu, submenu

I've got a menu with submenus - the function works.

first click, submenu open and if I click again the URL open.

```
$('.menu li.menu-item-has-children').click(function(e) {
    
    if ($(this).children('.sub-menu').parent().hasClass('clicked') != true) {
        $(this).children('.sub-menu').parent().addClass('clicked'); //show it
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

});
```

But now I need to check if, if the first one I clicked has got href attribute. Only if this exist go to url on second click. if not the submenu must close.

Anyone an idea?

Here is an example. The Menu maybe get 3 level menu, too. so I hope there is any idea toget this working

```js
$('nav .menu li.menu-item-has-children').each(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('current_page_item')) {
            $(this).addClass('clicked');
        }
    });


    $('.menu li.menu-item-has-children').click(function(e) {
        //check is submenu is not visible

        //console.log(this);

        //if ($(this).parent().find('.sub-menu').is(':visible') != true) {
        if ($(this).children('.sub-menu').parent().hasClass('clicked') != true) {
            //$(this).parent().find('.sub-menu').show(); //show it
            $(this).children('.sub-menu').parent().addClass('clicked'); //show it

            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });




    if ($('li.menu-item-has-children.clicked .sub-menu > li.menu-item-has-children.current-menu-ancestor.current-menu-parent').length) {
        //console.log('zweite Ebene ist geklickt');
        $('li.menu-item-has-children.clicked .sub-menu > li.menu-item-has-children.current-menu-ancestor.current-menu-parent').addClass('clicked');
    }

    if ($('li.menu-item-has-children.current-menu-ancestor').length) {
        //console.log('erste Ebene ist geklickt');
        $('li.menu-item-has-children.current-menu-ancestor').addClass('clicked');
    }
```

```css
/*  NAV
========================================== */
nav {
    background-color: rgba(230, 234, 242, 1);
    position: relative;
    z-index: 84;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 515px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 100px 40px 60px 40px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
    -o-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.55s cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
    -moz-transition: transform 0.55s cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
    -o-transition: transform 0.55s cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
    transition: transform 0.55s cubic-bezier(0.785, 0.135, 0.15, 0.86);
}
nav.show {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
}
nav.show ul.menu li {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -moz-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    -o-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
}
nav.show ul.menu > li:nth-child(1) {
    transition-delay: 0.15s;
}
nav.show ul.menu > li:nth-child(2) {
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
nav.show ul.menu > li:nth-child(3) {
    transition-delay: 0.45s;
}
nav.show ul.menu > li:nth-child(4) {
    transition-delay: 0.6s;
}
nav.show ul.menu > li:nth-child(5) {
    transition-delay: 0.75s;
}
nav.show ul.menu > li:nth-child(6) {
    transition-delay: 0.9s;
}
nav.show ul.menu > li:nth-child(7) {
    transition-delay: 1.05s;
}
nav.show ul.menu > li:nth-child(8) {
    transition-delay: 1.2s;
}
nav.show ul.menu > li:nth-child(9) {
    transition-delay: 1.35s;
}


/* Logged in menu */

nav.show ul#menu-mein-kdfb-intern-menu {
    margin-top: 15px;
}
nav.show ul#menu-mein-kdfb-intern-menu.menu > li:nth-child(1) {
    transition-delay: 1.05s;
}




@media (min-width: 667px) {
    nav {
        padding: 126px 25px 55px 55px;
    }
}
nav ul.menu {
    list-style-type: none;
}
nav ul.menu li {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(40px);
    -moz-transform: translateX(40px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(40px);
    -o-transform: translateX(40px);
    transform: translateX(40px);
    opacity: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
nav ul.menu li:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
nav ul.menu li a {
    color: #0E3683;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 39px;
    display: block;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 10px 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
nav ul.menu li a span {
    color: #0E3683;
}

nav ul.menu li.current-menu-ancestor > a,
nav ul.menu li.current_page_item > a,
nav ul.menu li a:hover {
    color: #B6327B;
}

/* 2. ebene */
nav .menu li li a {
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 33px;
}
/* 3. ebene */
nav .menu li li li a {
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 32px;
}

nav .menu li.menu-item-has-children:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -30px;
    background-image: url('assets/arrow_down_blue.svg');
    /*
        width: 17px;
        height: 38px;
        background-size: 100%;
    */
    width: 17px;
    height: 17px;
    background-size: contain;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -9px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);

}

/*sub menu*/
nav .menu .sub-menu {
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 30px;
    height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
nav .menu li.menu-item-has-children.clicked > .sub-menu {
    height: auto;
}



nav .menu li.menu-item-has-children.clicked:before {
    top: 30px;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}



nav .menu li .sub-menu {
    padding-left: 30px;
    margin-left: 0;
}

nav .menu li li .sub-menu {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

nav .menu li li.menu-item-has-children:before {
    height: 27px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -18px;
}

nav .menu .sub-menu li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
nav .menu .sub-menu li a {
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-transform: none;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="mainmen show">
  <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
    <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children"><a href="https://google.com">1 Click: Open Sub menu - 2 Click: Go to URL Menu Item</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://google.com">Link 1</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://google.com">Link 2</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children"><a>Only Toggle Submenu Item</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://google.com">Sub menu Item 1</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://google.com">Sub menu Item 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children "><a>Only Toggle Menu Item</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="https://google.com">Link 1</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children"><a>Only toggle Menu Item</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-post"><a href="https://google.com">Link 1</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="https://google.com">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
    </li>
        
    </ul>
   
    
   
    </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: It would help to see the HTML in order to create a working example, however `is('[href]')` should do what you need.

Comment: You could try doing something like this.. maybe..
`if(element.attr('href') != null){

}else{

}`

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the relevant markup? This would make it much easier to give you a working solution.

Comment: I've edit my post - anyone an idea?